# How to redirect when diagram info is clicked

Tags: powerbi

I am just starting with power bi and I am having a problem and it is that I cannot find in the documentation the way to redirect the page or change the graphic when clicking on the graphic.
[image]

Is there a way to do that or is it not possible?, all I have is to modify the interactions but not redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Cosmosmulti you can do it in the edit interactions pane on the top left once you click on the visual.

Hope this helps with what you want!

Ps: If this works or any other answer works please take a moment to upvote the answer and click on the tick mark. Thank you.